# Display bootsrap modal with passed id

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a tab in my page named popular, In which multiple rows are dynamically loaded from db. It also contains a button in which their is a specific id and code. I am trying to display the selected button row data in modal. But i am not able to do this.When i put my modal div inside the `php` while loop, It displays all the row code one by one in faded modal. Any suggestions please.

**code**

```
 <div id="popular" class="tab-pane counties-pane active animated fadeIn">
 <?php
  $q=mysqli_query($con,"  SELECT c.* , sc.* , sm.* ,ca.* from store_category sc INNER JOIN store_manufacture sm ON sm.sm_id=sc.store_id INNER JOIN categories ca ON ca.cat_id=sc.cat_id INNER JOIN coupons c on c.c_sc_id=sc.sc_id ");
 while($row1=mysqli_fetch_array($q,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
  $h = strpos($row1['sm_link'], 'http');
  ?>
  <div class="coupon-wrapper row">
   <div class="coupon-data col-sm-2 text-center">
   <div class="savings text-center">
   <div>
   <div class="large"><?php echo $row1['c_name'] ?></div>
   <div class="type"><?php echo $row1['sm_brand_name'] ?></div>
     </div></div></div>
     <div class="coupon-contain col-sm-7">
    <h4 class="coupon-title"><a href="<?php echo ($h !== FALSE)?$row1['sm_link']:"http://".$row1['sm_link'] ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $row1['c_description']?></a></h4></div>
<div class="button-contain col-sm-3 text-center">
 <p class="btn-code" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".couponModal">
<span class="partial-code"><?php echo $row1['c_code'] ?></span> 
<span class="btn-hover">Get Code</span></p> </div></div>
 <?php
 }
 ?>
  </div>

 <!--Modal-->
    <div class="coupon_modal modal fade couponModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="couponModal_<?php echo $row1['c_id'] ?>">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true"><i class="ti-close"></i></span> </button>
    <div class="coupon_modal_content">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 text-center">
    <h2><?php echo $row1['c_name'] ?></h2>
     <p><?php echo $row1['c_description'] ?></p>
     </div>
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-12">
     <h5 class="text-center text-uppercase m-t-20 text-muted">Click below to get your coupon code</h5>
      </div><div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4 col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3"> <a href="#" target="_blank" class="coupon_code alert alert-info">
<span class="coupon_icon"><i class="ti-cut hidden-xs"></i></span>  <?php echo $row1['c_code'] ?></a></div>
      </div> </div> </div>
 </div></div></div>
```

Comment: have you some JS part taking care of the button ID and sending it to the modal ?

Comment: no. I am sending id through `data-target`

Comment: seen that, but using a class won't help much, it will open with only one row, or the first one in the flow. 1) in your loop, you put *one* modal per item with unique ID (heavy...) **or** 2) you put one modal and you target it with the ID, then load the targeted item (ie: [example plugin](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/modal/#varying-modal-content) )

Comment: You need to use an ID for the modals, so I second @OldPadawan

Comment: @OldPadawan can you please give me some sample code?

Comment: I do not use bootstrap, that won't be easy :/ I could show an example of what I'm using, but that will only give you the idea of *how it works*, that won't fix your code.

Comment: sure.. it may be helpful

Comment: @tabia : check this [example](https://pastebin.com/L7c0ABZb) to see how it works with jQuery, then adapt to your needs...

Comment: @tabia : made a live example on [phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/4g0k-bbrp), just run-f9

Comment: @OldPadawan thanks for this. It is helpfull but now the modal displayed is disabled. The screen get disabled. I can't close the modal untill i refresh it

Comment: when working on/with a modal, you always have some kind of standard identicals parameters: overlay (that puts main focus on the modal) : here, I put a very little opacity: 0.1 = 10%) and closing. here, I added the onclick event on the overlay. You can choose not to put an overlay, or allow to click anywhere outside the modal to close the overlay/modal, it's up to you/parameters you choose.